# Value of type 'NSLinguisticTag' has no member 'range'

Tags: swift, swift4, nslinguistictagger

I have text direction code its working good with swift 3 but after migration to swift 4, I got error

```
let tagScheme = [NSLinguisticTagScheme.language]
    let tagger    = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: tagScheme, options: 0)
    tagger.string = self.text
    let lang      = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: NSLinguisticTagScheme.language,
                                      tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil)

    if lang?.range(of: "he") != nil ||  lang?.range(of: "ar") != nil { //Value of type 'NSLinguisticTag' has no member 'range' 
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    } else {
        self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    }
```

Anyone know how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Swift 4, `NSLinguisticTagger` returns tags not as (optional)
strings, but as (optional) values of [`NSLinguisticTag`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictag):

```
public struct NSLinguisticTag : RawRepresentable, Equatable, Hashable {
    public init(_ rawValue: String)
    public init(rawValue: String)
}
```

You get the underlying string with the `rawValue` property:

```
 if let lang = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: .language, tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil) {
    print(lang.rawValue)
    if lang.rawValue.hasPrefix("he") { ... }
}
```

If you want to check for equality and not for containment then
you can also define your own `NSLinguisticTag` constants:

```
extension NSLinguisticTag {
    static let hebrew = NSLinguisticTag("he")
}
```

and use them as

```
if let lang = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: .language, tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil) {
    if lang == .hebrew { ... }
}
```

Another option would be to define a custom computed property

```
extension NSLinguisticTag {
    var isRightToLeft: Bool {
        return rawValue.hasPrefix("he") || rawValue.hasPrefix("ar")
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
if let lang = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: .language, tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil) {
    if lang.isRightToLeft { ... }
}
```